# "model = RoomSerializer NameError: name 'RoomSerializer'

Tags: django-rest-framework

my serializer.py in my api file is giving me this error "model = RoomSerializer
NameError: name 'RoomSerializer' is not defined", when I run try running my server.  I have tried stack overflow still no solution. Please someone help

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = RoomSerializer
fields = ('id', 'code', 'host', 'guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip', 'created_at')

Comment: Please detail more your problem, and put your code snippets with proper formatting. and What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework import serializers 

from .models import Room

 
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Room
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'host', 'guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip', 'created_at')
```

In Class Meta, you should specify a model (class) name in front of the model attribute.
In your case your model (Class) name is Room. Don't specify the serializer class name.